# Prevention of sinkhole attacks

Tags: attacks, attack-prevention, wireless

I have read about many approaches to launch and detect [sinkhole attacks](http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Sinkhole_%28Computer_network%29) in  wireless (sensor) networks. Yet I couldn't find any (good) articles to read about the prevention/avoidance of sinkhole attacks. The one I have found is specific to AODV Protocol in Mobile Ad hoc Networks.

How do I prevent sinkhole attacks?

Comment: It is always better to [read the rules](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) before posting. Recommendation questions are explicitly off-topic here. Please re-phrase your post (e.g. "how do I prevent a sinkhole attack?")

Comment: @DeerHunter Is it okay now?

Comment: I'm not sure that a sinkhole is an attack, just like a honeypot is not an attack.  It seems to be an infrastructure arrangement that helps detect intrusions.

Comment: Sinkhole is the network equivalent of honeypot. Sinkhole can form the basis of many other attacks. Forming a sinkhole itself is considered as an attack in all the papers.

Comment: In the article you linked, I could not find "sinkhole attack", and it seems mostly the article talks about a sinkhole as a tool to help analysis. Of course a tool can be used to gather info to help do an attack later but I wouldn't consider the tool itself an attack. For example a keyboard logger logs keystrokes, but I wouldn't consider using a keyboard logger to be an attack, just reconnaissance. You said `Forming a sinkhole itself is considered as an attack in all the papers`. Do you have an example paper?

Comment: @clarity123 https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1505/1505.01941.pdf

Comment: When reading related paper, it sounds `blackhole / packet drop attack`. It is an DDoS attack that hijack Wireless sensor network traffics and send them to void. So searching keywords like `packet drop attack` or `spoofing network attack` should give you some clue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a sensor/IoT device network, a potential way to avoid a [DNS Sinkhole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_sinkhole), in particular, would be to only use a trusted DNS that you own.

The problem with that approach is that a [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) Name Server could still pass down unroutable addresses to your custom server, so it would have to be modified to not accept such addresses.

Or, you could skip the whole DNS circus and use hard-coded IP addresses. That way, you don't have to worry about rogue DNS entries if you aren't even looking them up. Again, this is specific to the DNS Sinkhole attack and may be vulnerable to other types of attacks.